# Loading of caffe model in the memory

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I have to load the model every time I train it. Loading of model takes around 3.9 second. I want to load the model once in the memory, so that I can use it continuously for training.

Answer (score 1):

```
caffe/build/tools/caffe train --solver solver_file.prototxt --weights pretrained_model.caffemodel -gpu 0
```

In the above code, you should use your model name instead of `pretrained_model` and then, at the beginning of the training, this model is loaded and would not be loaded again.

https://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/finetune_flickr_style.html